# How to use the telegram API to create a chat application?

Tags: android, api

I want to create a chating application for android using the telegram API available. I am new to using the external library. Can anybody give me a bit idea about how to use the API to build a chat application? Where do i put the ApiId and Api hash? The app still crashes

Comment: can you get any help?

Answer (score 10):

telegram full source code is available on github..find it out from the telegram website...import the project in android studio ..Search for the API key in src files....replace the telegram prrvious key with your own key..

Comment: I couldn't find API key word inside src of telegram source code.

Comment: @AhesanaliMomin check out BuildVars.java file

Comment: @SamerZuhair also i couldn't find user interface in layout files. I think moat of ui built using java.

Comment: @AhesanaliMomin yeah::: setContentView(new View(this), new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));\

Comment: Thanks, but still they are using more stuff from java side